# how to resolve libx265 dependency issue on CentOS7?

Tags: centos, yum, dependencies

I'm trying to run a

```
# yum update
```

On my system and I'm getting the following message:

```
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: ffmpeg-libs-2.6.5-1.el7.nux.x86_64 (@nux-dextop)
           Requires: libx265.so.51()(64bit)
           Removing: x265-libs-1.6-1.el7.nux.x86_64 (@nux-dextop)
               libx265.so.51()(64bit)
           Updated By: x265-libs-1.7-1.el7.x86_64 (epel-spotify)
              ~libx265.so.59()(64bit)
Error: Package: vlc-core-2.2.1-6.el7.nux.x86_64 (@nux-dextop)
           Requires: libx265.so.51()(64bit)
           Removing: x265-libs-1.6-1.el7.nux.x86_64 (@nux-dextop)
               libx265.so.51()(64bit)
           Updated By: x265-libs-1.7-1.el7.x86_64 (epel-spotify)
              ~libx265.so.59()(64bit)
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

How do I solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, run `yum clean all` and try again.  Also verify that you aren't excluding any packages from the `nux-desktop` repo.  If you are still having issues after this, contact the repo maintainer to let him know about a potentially broken package.

http://li.nux.ro/repos.html

> If you want to request a package drop me an email at rpm at li.nux.ro or post on the forums.